# Linear Layout behind ImageView in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Let me explain i have a xml like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/img_circle" />
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/llFirstScreen"
       android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgCircle"
       android:background="@drawable/layout_view_round_corner"
       android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/mapCurrentLocation"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="TextView1"
       android:textColor="@color/lblTextColor"
       android:textSize="@dimen/lblTextLarge"
       android:textStyle="normal" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="TextView2"
       android:textColor="@color/lblHintColor2"
       android:textSize="@dimen/lblTextMedium"
       android:textStyle="normal" >
    </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And this gives me Image and TextViews next to it

[image: Layout i currently have]

But i want to accomplish something like this

[image: Layout i would like to have]

that TextView Background is extended (padding maybe) at the half of the Rounded Image (behind it) so that it looks like its "part" of the image. Or I was thinking of Making a view with background white that goes behind TextView so that it looks that way. But wanted to ask here maybe if there is a better way to do this.

I hope i was clear in explaining this (That is why I added pictures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to use demo with your xml file and you can check below code. I had to give static height and width of the `ImageView` to achieve result.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFirstScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgCarCircle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgCarCircle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mapCurrentLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textStyle="normal"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text2"
            android:textStyle="normal"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCarCircle"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is what i needed. I wasn't sure

Answer (score 0):

try these: 
first solution: change this

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/llFirstScreen"
       android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgCircle"
       android:background="@drawable/layout_view_round_corner"
       android:orientation="vertical">
```

to this:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/llFirstScreen"
       android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgCircle"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" // or just figure your image width and set this programatically
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/layout_view_round_corner"
       android:orientation="vertical">
```

second solution: it to use [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) which is a bit hard to handle.